# How to Remove Unknown Stain from Bathtub?

Tags: bathtub, cleaning, stain

I recently moved into a new home and want to remove a stain from the bathtub. The tub is older and almost a dark pink in colour so stains show up well. I have already tried scrubbing it with Comet, Bleach/Javex spray, and CLR Bathroom foam, but nothing seems to be doing the trick. Anyone have any suggestions? I'm not sure what it could be... Thanks!

[image: Tub]

Comment: not a stain, the finish is chipped and/or flaking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks far more like surface damage than 'staining' or any type of removable discolouration.

I'd say it depends what on it's made of as to your course of action. 'Plastic' [fibreglass etc], or cast iron?
If it's cast iron, it's worth having it taken away to be properly re-enamelled [DIY attempts usually look very home-made.]
Plastic, not worth it; buy a new tub. You could, of course, repeat what the last owner did - it looks like it's been re-finished once before… but that's what happens to it, especially with coarse cleaners.

<sup>From another answer - I wouldn't pay 500 to have a plastic tub re-coated. You can have a fancy new one for that. A cast iron bath, on the other hand, would be 2 grand or so to replace.</sup>

Comment: If the bathroom generally is somehow in much better condition than the tub, professional recoating is a good call.    But, assuming the rest of the bathroom has aged also, I'd avoid replacing the tub.  It would require at least some retiling and replumbing work.  There's a lot of investment and in the end you still have an old bathroom.  Don't waste your money.   Do nothing for now.  Live with it until you're ready to do a full renovation.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it was spray painted once upon the time and the paint is coming off.

New spray coat will cost you about $500 done by professionals and you can choose new color.